# mysql_affected_rows() work-around?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update

I'm using this code as part of an email confirmation script.  It works great, except I can't figure out a way to distinguish between when somebody has provided an invalid email address vs when they have simply refreshed the page (ie. already confirmed their account).  The only think I can think of is putting a time stamp field in the `users` table that always gets updated, but I'm hoping there is a better way.  I thought `REPLACE` would do the trick, but, while `email` is unique, it is not the primary key.

```
if (isset ($email, $token, $correctToken)){    
    $success = FALSE; //Set the $success variable so that we don't get an error when testing for it later
    if ($token == $correctToken) {
        $confirm = mysql_query("UPDATE users
                        SET conf = 'TRUE'
                        WHERE email = '$email'");
        if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {
            echo "Thank you!  Your email address is confirmed and your account is actived.";
            $success = TRUE;
        }
    }
    if (!$success) {
        echo "There was a problem with the confirmation.  Try the link in your email again or contact us at Support@WiseRenters.com";
        // Send  email to admin to notify of error
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the advice!
Billy

EDIT: The `$email` and `$token` variables are provided through $_GET or $_POST, in case that wasn't obvious.

Comment: Why not redirect them to a separate page for the confirmation? This way they won't be able to refresh the page if it is successful.

Comment: I like that option better than adding to the database.  What about setting a $_SESSION variable on success?  That should work, right?

Comment: Redirection would stop them from refreshing, but what if they click the link in their email again? See my answer.

Comment: Do like @Aknosis said. Redirect to another page. Then you get rid of the $_GEt-variables too. Good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A redirection would stop them from refreshing - but what if they click the link in their email again?

You should check if the current user is activated or not.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, conf FROM users WHERE email = '{$email}'";
$exec = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
list( $id, $conf ) = mysql_fetch_row($exec);

if( $conf ) {
    // Redirect them to their profile with a message saying "your account has already been activated"
    header("Location: /profile?already_activated");
    exit;
}

// your code
$confirm = mysql_query("UPDATE users
                    SET conf = 'TRUE'
                    WHERE id = '{$id}'");
```

In response to your comment:

Keep in mind this will only add an additional query for a user who has not activated yet. If they have activated then the redirect occurs and the page is still running only 1 query.

To optimize this a bit, you can select the user ID and confirmation status based on the email address. Then, if they do need to be activated, you can activate them based on user ID instead of email. Since an integer key is much faster, the combined time of the 2 queries will be about the same as the 1 query where you are updating based on a string column. I updated the code to reflect this.

Also, this page will probably not be accessed very frequently. Any optimizations from here would really be micro- and not really that helpful.

By the way I hope you are using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the email, and that `conf` is a boolean true/false not a string 'true'/'false'.

Comment: Adding another query to check and see if the user is already confirmed seems to solve the problem; it's the best option so far, but is there a more efficient way?  Thank you for the response!

Comment: I updated my answer. You can slightly optimize it but really, running 2 small queries instead of 1 is not going to hurt you that much. Remember that an activation page probably isn't going to get much traffic relative to the rest of your site, so optimizations here can only help so much.

Comment: P.S. You should also do the redirect that Aknosis was suggesting in addition to the confirmation check.

Comment: I see the edit - Fantastic!  Thank you very much!  And the answer to your last two questions is yes.  I really appreciate your answer!